# PhpStorm после обновление не форматирует код

Tags: phpstorm, форматирование

Обновил *PhpStorm* до *9.0.1 (лицензия)* — перестал форматироваться код.

Ассоциации с *php* выставлены.

Файл `sample.php`, `sample.module` — форматирует, а `sample.new.inc` выдает сообщение:

> No lines changed: code is already properly formatted

и все, хотя там все криво.

Как исправить поведение программы?

Comment: Извиняюсь, не файлы, конечно, а код.

Comment: вы можете отредактировать свой вопрос, нажав [edit].